# Serial communication with Xtralien potentiostat not working?

Tags: labview

I am trying to set up a potentiostat Xtralien by Ossila with LabView.

The way the instrument works in a string-in, string-out, so far so good. 
The built-in code examples that are provided by the manufacturer contain firstly a string-in, string-out LabView program and secondly a preliminary console to record an I-V sweep (https://www.ossila.com/pages/basic-xtralien-commands-in-labview, https://www.ossila.com/pages/xtralien-x100-command-list). In the string interface, I can enter 'CLOI hello' and the device responds 'hello world', so far so good. If I proceed any further and send i.e. a 'smu1 measurev' command connecting to some photodiode, I just receive a near-zero value back, setting 'smu1 set voltage 0.5' or similar does not lead to an output voltage either. Running the sweep program over said photodiode gives noise in the µA range. 
EDIT: All involved hardware components were double-checked.

Where am I doing something wrong? Is the error arising from communication errors or...? Has someone experienced this so far?

Comment: Have you tried to send any of these commands with a different serial terminal tool such as Putty?

Answer (score 0):

Received the answer from the Ossila support. The Xtralien X200 drivers were recently updated (http://files.ossila.com/source-measure-unit/Ossila-X200-SMU-Instr.zip), and you need to switch on each SMU channel sperately. This was implemented in a subVI in the Instrumentation -> X200.
Hope I helped all who get a similar problem in the future!